# Это pluggable функция

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне нужно использовать функцию `check_ajax_referer()` в плагине для проверки переданного значения, но в описании пишется:

> Это pluggable функция — т.е. её можно заменить из плагина. Это значит, что она будет работать (подключается) только после подключения всех плагинов, а до этого момента функция еще не определена... Поэтому нельзя вызывать эту и зависящие от неё функции прямо из кода плагина. Их нужно вызывать через хук plugins_loaded или позднее, например хук init.

Значит этот хук `add_action('wp_ajax_(action)', 'my_action_callback');` нужно вызывать из `plugins_loaded` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не так.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_action', 'my_action_callback')
```

ставят прямо в тело плагина. Если у плагина один файл, то в него.

Есть [описание последовательности вызова хуков](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). Из неё видно, что сначала сработает `plugins_loaded`, потом `init`, и только потом уж будут вызваны хуки ajax (они не указаны в статье по ссылке, но вызываются они после полной загрузки ядра).

Возможно, у вас есть стандартное непонимание. На самом деле, `add_action()` не делает ничего, она только заносит информацию во внутреннюю таблицу хуков WordPress. Ваша функция `my_action_callback` будет вызвана, как я описал выше, после полной загрузки ядра.

Так что вставляйте указанный выше `add_action` прямо в тело плагина. А `check_ajax_referer()` должен быть внутри вашей `my_action_callback`.

Код вашего плагина должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Cool Plugin
 * Plugin URI: https://cool.org/
 * Description: Coolest plugin.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Me
 * Author URI: https://cool.org/
 * Text Domain: cool
 * Domain Path: /languages/
 *
 * @package cool
 */

function my_action_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'cool_action' );

    // Some code...
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_cool_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```